# Deploying an app to users' appspot

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working on a Python App, which runs on App Engine. Is there a way I can publish the app on each customers' appSpot account, so that the App uses the users' cloud storage? Instead of running the App on my AppSpot account and all the users storing the data on my Cloud space?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but why wouldn't you wan't to run it on yours?

Comment: @Trufa Google has restrictions on number of API calls I can make, (approx 500 per sec.) which could be easily breached. So, the app would not be scalable above a limit. This API limit is absolute and cannot be increased with a premium plan.

Comment: Fair enough, good luck! It might be still a good start bur I see your point.

Comment: The short-term quotas actually can be increased by contacting Google if you're legitimately reaching or approaching them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

You just need to have each client create an App Engine account with an application to which you have administrator access. You can adjust the settings on the application to forbid downloads of your code by the other administrators if that's appropriate for your agreement with the client. This also allows the clients to be billed directly for their instances' usage, and makes it completely impossible for data to leak between different clients' instances.

Using multiple applications for multiple clients who are licensing your application almost certainly does not violate part 4.4 of the TOS, although don't take this as legal advice.

Comment: I traveled in the direction quite a bit. But the problem here is only geeks could use the app then. Most people would like to do a next-next-next-finish installation. Getting them create an App Engine account, asking them to uncheck "code-download" etc. would just kill the product. Otherwise, I may have to scrape their AppEngine page and automate the creation process with some script. That is bound to fail sooner or later. Also, hacks are always bad for products :-\

Comment: Codevalley: true; this is really only appropriate for licensing software for customers to run fairly independently.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. The app is hosted and run in the administrator's account which would be you. What you can do is, release the source code and point your users do install it in their appspot account, just like creating a new application.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's not exactly what you need. But it can give you an idea where to go. Please check [DryDrop project](http://drydrop.binaryage.com). There is small Python application you can ask each user to install on their account, then they can configure it to fetch your site files from your GitHub repo through webhooks functionality. I didn't try it, but, theoretically, you update your site, commit it to your repo, and all users get your updated application automatically. You can share your thoughts if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. If it's an open source app that you're giving away, you can publish the source and instruct users to upload it to their own accounts.

If you're selling the app, displaying ads or otherwise trying to monetize the service, you probably want to stick with one instance. Using multiple instances to avoid paying for quota usage is direct violation of the [App Engine TOS](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html):

> 4.4. You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a
>   single Application or otherwise access
>   the Service in a manner intended to
>   avoid incurring fees.

Answer (score 0):

No. Writing an application that deploys other applications is in violation of the terms of service.

Note we don't have any 'hard' limits - those limits that aren't billing enabled can be increased on application to us if you provide a reasonable use-case.

Comment: Processing limits looks to be absolute: http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/billing.html#cpu 500 Calls/sec.That is the concern.

Comment: That, like all the other quotas, can be increased if needed. The whole point of App Engine is that it scales indefinitely!

Comment: In fact, the last sentence in that paragraph says as much.

Comment: I felt that is more for temporary spikes in traffice eg: "Your site gets in the Yahoo! home page". Right?

Comment: @Codevalley No. App Engine is for apps that want to scale, and we'll increase quotas appropriately.